# Is there any way to programmatically determine when an app was last opened?

Tags: java, android, usage-statistics

I would like to know when an app (i.e., Facebook or WhatsApp) was last opened.

Without root, is there any way to programmatically determine when an app was last opened in Android?

**Important Info:**

One issue I have regarding previous suggestions is, if I keep some variation of log then I wouldn't be able to determine when an app was last used if it was used before my Android application was installed.

Comment: keep a logfile that is updated when opening-closing the app

Comment: save app opening time in to preference and updated it next time , now for the very first time you start your application , check that preference value and set your logic as you want !!!!!

Comment: Note that the full system log is only visible if you have root.

Comment: @Radhe He means ANY app, not his app.

Comment: sorry @Bevor , he didn't mention his app or every app , so gave  suggestion . anyway even I want to know for every app ,share solution if you get #fraruphe.

Answer (score 2):

From google examples:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AppUsageStatistics

```
public List<UsageStats> getUsageStatistics(int intervalType) {
        // Get the app statistics since one year ago from the current time.
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);

        List<UsageStats> queryUsageStats = mUsageStatsManager
                .queryUsageStats(intervalType, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                        System.currentTimeMillis());

        if (queryUsageStats.size() == 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "The user may not allow the access to apps usage. ");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    getString(R.string.explanation_access_to_appusage_is_not_enabled),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mOpenUsageSettingButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mOpenUsageSettingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS));
                }
            });
        }
        return queryUsageStats;
    }
```

And them you can use this:

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStats.html#getLastTimeUsed()

```
if( mUsageStats.getPackageName().equals("YOUR PACKAGE NAME")){
    mUsageStats.getLastTimeUsed();
}
```

Comment: I think so, the only thing It was added in API level 21

Comment: how does this retain a date for when an application was last used

Comment: I have no idea, It's a new feature in Android API level 21